# Using JavaScript + D3 3.x code in SAS to create HTML output

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, sas, jsfiddle

I am facing a challenge in executing code from here: https://jsfiddle.net/zwk29rcs/1/ on SAS EG. The code in the link creates a Sankey diagram using JavaScript and D3 3.x and want to use SAS EG to create the same diagram for internal data.

I tried using PROC STREAM & PROC TEMPLATE but it generated blank HTML output.

Would greatly appreciate if you can guide me for this project.

Thank you!

Input data Code for jsfiddle:

```
var data = [{
    "source": "A",
        "target": "X",
        "value": 5
}, {
    "source": "A",
        "target": "Y",
        "value": 7
}, {
    "source": "A",
        "target": "Z",
        "value": 6
}, {
    "source": "B",
        "target": "X",
        "value": 2
}, {
    "source": "B",
        "target": "Y",
        "value": 9
}, {
    "source": "B",
        "target": "Z",
        "value": 4
}, {
    "source": "X",
        "target": "L",
        "value": 5
}
];
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you trying to create the above from a data set? What format does that data set have? Do you need EG to create the whole code from JSFiddle?

Comment: SAS can directly create Sankey diagrams as well directly to HTML https://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2015/03/21/sankey-diagrams/

Comment: Can you show the SAS code you tried ?

Comment: @Richard: Please see SAS code here: https://github.com/tanmaykhole208/tanmayk/blob/master/proc%20stream

Comment: @Reeza: Yes, I need the whole code from jsfiddle to work on SAS. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, just use a plain data step. So change your STREAM statements to PUT statements and add some conditional logic so that the stuff before the data is printed on the first record and the stuff on the last of the record is printed after.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the brute force method, just write directly to an HTML file.

Use PUT statements to push the direct text and you can also conditionally just when to put certain statements.

Here's a rough, untested example:

```
data _null_;

file 'demo.html'; *name and properties of file to be created;
set source_data; *input data set;

if _n_ =1 then do; *put all beginning text before data;

put '<!doctype html>';
put '<html>';
put '<head>';
....

put ' var data = [';
end;

*******************************************************;
*create data portion;
*******************************************************;

put    '{"source": "' source_variable '",';
put    '"target": "' x_variable '",';
put    '"value": ' value_variable;
put    '}';

*only place comma between elements so last one does not need one;
if not eof then do;
    put ',';
end;

*place all lines of code after;
if eof then do;
put '];';

*rest of code;
put ' graph = {
 "nodes": [],
 "links": []
  };';

end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, Reeza! I tried using your method but the generated HTML file is blank.

Comment: Thank you, Reeza!!! Your solution worked. I was facing issue with hyperlinking the .js file. Once I added "https" to .js & .css file, it was able to load functions!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it formatted in that hard to read style?

Anyway it is easy to generate that with a data step.

Since you didn't show what data you have in SAS that you are trying to pass let's make a dataset that looks like the data in the javascript code you posted so we have something to program with.

```
data have ;
  input source $ target $ value ;
cards;
A X 5
A Y 7
A Z 6
B X 2
B Y 9
B Z 4
X L 5
;
```

Here is a data step code to generate that data into the json like style you need.

```
filename test temp;
data _null_;
  file test;
  set have end=eof;
  format _character_ $quote. ;
  if _n_=1 then put 'var data =' / '[' @;
  else put ',' @;
  put '{"source": ' source ',"target": ' target ',"value": ' value '}' ;
  if eof then put '];';
run;
```

Result:

```
var data =
[{"source": "A" ,"target": "X" ,"value": 5 }
,{"source": "A" ,"target": "Y" ,"value": 7 }
,{"source": "A" ,"target": "Z" ,"value": 6 }
,{"source": "B" ,"target": "X" ,"value": 2 }
,{"source": "B" ,"target": "Y" ,"value": 9 }
,{"source": "B" ,"target": "Z" ,"value": 4 }
,{"source": "X" ,"target": "L" ,"value": 5 }
];
```

It should not be that hard to direct this output into the place you need it.  It is also not that hard to generalize the method to output any dataset, especially if the dataset variable names match the names you want for your json fields.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. My question was not about the dataset formatting but to make use of code from jsfiddle for internal data.

Comment: Huh?  What data are you passing to jsfiddle if it isn't a dataset that you have in SAS?